# Jenkins - Restrict Job execution based on user/roles

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to configure Jenkins jobs so that users can run only some jobs. For exemple: user1 can run jobs for deploy on QA environment, but not on Production environment. user2 can run jobs for deploy on Production environment and so on... how can I achieve this requirement on Jenkins?

Many thanks

Savio Barros

Comment: post a response after using that plugin

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

It may help

Comment: I just want to tell which user can run a particular job. The Role Strategy plugins seems to be pretty complicated to achieve this requirement, since I didn't see any option to select users/jobs. Is there a better option?

Comment: @SavioBarros. Check this video. you can achieve what you wanted with this same plugin. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvFungzXI5s